# Top questions featured tab number changing color to gray

Tags: bug, microsoft-edge

When I hold my mouse on the "featured" tab the number flashes gray for a moment. 
And when I move my mouse quickly over it it will stay gray.

[image: featured black]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open Edge
2. Go to Stack Overflow (not logged in)
3. Hover or move over the "featured" tab